# How to extract documentation from phpDocumentor directly into MySQL

Tags: php, javadoc, phpdoc

I would like to make my own documentation viewer, however the PHPDOC (JavaDoc) format suits me quite well for defining structure.

Is there a project to harvest PHPDOC tags from the source files and simply store it into SQL?

Comment: probably might be faster and easier to write a simple crawler that would suit your needs..

Answer (score -1):

Someone put together a reflection based docblock tool for phpDocumenter https://github.com/phpDocumentor/ReflectionDocBlock that can be useful. For me, I wrapped this into a tool for grabbing docs out of odd files like SQL, Javascript, and css for inclusion into larger documentation.  It's been a while ago, but the approach did work as long as the file is reachable; ie, get a list of files, loop through them, extract the docBlocks, do whatever, move on to the next one kinda of approach.